# Don't want to download all objects

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm having a hard time understanding how I should structure my iOS app with regards to how Firebase works. I've got a few thousand users with my current implementation (not using firebase currently), but using `.childAdded` will give me all of the items in my db (of course to start with) but I'm trying to build something with `.childAdded` that allows me to say download the first 20 items, then as they scroll the tableview it downloads the next 20 items. My users post a lot of photos and their feed would be blown up with the amount of posts that `.childAdded` returns.

Thoughts on what to do?

Comment: can you share your request example with its ref?

Comment: Closed? Oh man such power... wow.. literally talking about a tableview and downloading objects. Must feel good to have such admin (jackass)power..again why I don't care to use this site much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can see the documentation that [Explains Queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query)

You can go to the part that says limitToFirst.
For Example this says to limit to last 10:

```
var rootRef = firebase.database.ref();
var usersRef = rootRef.child("users");
var usersQuery = usersRef.limitToLast(10);

usersQuery.isEqual(usersRef);  // false
usersQuery.isEqual(usersRef.limitToLast(10));  // true
usersQuery.isEqual(rootRef.limitToLast(10));  // false
usersQuery.isEqual(usersRef.orderByKey().limitToLast(10));  // false
```

Answer (score 2):

This may help you better understand how to convert Firebase Queries into equivalent SQL Queries.

https://firebase.googleblog.com/2013/10/queries-part-1-common-sql-queries.html#paginate

```
// fetch page 2 of messages
new Firebase("https://examples-sql-queries.firebaseio.com/messages")
.startAt(2) // assumes the priority is the page number
.endAt(2)
.once('value', function(snap) {
   console.log('messages in range', snap.val());
});
```